# Adding elements to global list object in scala

Tags: list, scala

Allright guys, pardon me if this question has already been asked. Yet another Scala newbie question. So for example if I want to have a global List object which can be used as a place holder container, in Java I can easily do;

```
//share list object
private List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
void add(String el)
{
 strList.add(e);
}

static void main(String[] args) { 
{
  add("36 Chambers");
  out.println(strList.get(0));//assume only element
}
```

Similarly, if I simulate the same syntax in Scala - I end up with `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`. How can one achieve similar with simple Scala?

```
  private var strList: List[String] = Nil
  def add(el: String) {
    strList :+ el
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {   
    add("36 Chambers")
    println(s(0)) //assume only element
  }
```

Comment: Won't bother writing an answer since you've already accepted one, but `List` appears to be totally the wrong collection for your purposes - you should use a `Vector`, which has both fast append and prepend, and is the standard implementation of an indexed collection for fast lookup. You can write `strVector = strVector :+ el`, or the short version `strVector :+= el`.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge please add an answer - this helps others to easily dig and find relevant answers like yours. I will give you a vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To strictly answer your question:**

```
private var strList: List[String] = Nil
def add(el: String) {
       strList = el :: strList;
}
```

You are using the wrong operator. You need to use `::`. And you need to update inline because a `List` is of immutable length.

I'm switching the `el` and `strList` because `::` is right associative, which means the method comes from the object to the right of the `::` operator.

Also, the `::` operator will perform a prepend, which means your elements will be in reverse order.

You can either call reverse at the end(before usage etc) or if you want something semantically similar to a Java `ArrayList` perhaps consider a Scala `ListBuffer`, a mutable collection to which you can append.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer;
private var strList: ListBuffer[String] = Nil
def add(el: String) {
       strList += el;
}
```